# How to convert a hierarchy list to json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, hierarchy

I am using ASP.NET MVC3

I have a hierarchy list with this type:

```
public class TreeNode
{
public int id;
public int title;
public int parentid;
}
var myHierarchyList=new List<TreeNode>();
//(the tree has a root with id=1 and parentid=0 and title=root)
```

I need a function to generate json data from myHierarchyList. somthing like this:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "text":"cat1",
    "childrens":[{
        "id":2,
        "text":"cat2"
    },{
        "id":3,
        "text":"cat3",
        "childrens":[{
            "id":4,
            "text":"cat4"
        },{
            "id": 8,
            "text":"cat5"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What does the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) output?

Comment: I have an idea myself, but do not know how to implement it! the idea is to define a new class like: public class node{public int id; public int title; public List<node> childs} and build the tree into this.

Comment: Did you try using the JavaScriptSerializer class though? No use reinventing the wheel if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the composite design pattern. This allows you to build up the hierarchy of different objects and recursively loop through and use a stringbuilder to generate xml, json html etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;

    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static string JsonSerialize<T>(this T obj) where T : class
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
                return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }

        public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(this T obj, string json) where T : class
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                return serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
            }
        }
    }
}


...................


void somefuntion()
{
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
    ...Do stuff to myObject .........
    ............

    // Get myObject as a Json String
    string json = myObject.JsonSerialize();
}
```

Comment: The     ...Do stuff to myObject ......... Part, is also a part of my question too! here is a recursive way to build the hierarchy object: http://www.dhirajranka.com/?p=30        Please update your answer according to this. so i will mark your answer as the answer :)